# logarithmic potential of harmonic moment

Tags: notation

What is the symbol behind the integration means in logarithmic potential ?
Let's say $$x_{\mu}(z)=\int_D \ln|z-\xi|d\mu(\xi)$$ What does $\xi$ means ?
I have been studying harmonic moment and I come across this term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\xi$ (the Greek letter "xi") is just the integration variable. You might as well rename it $w$ if you like...

Comment: Then how to integrate the integral above if we integrate w.r.t. $\xi$ ? Treat the integrand as constant ?

Comment: No, it is not constant, it is the function $\xi \mapsto \ln |z-\xi|$. You can only explicitly integrate this if you know what measure $\mu$ is.

Comment: but isn't the function is  $z \rightarrow ln|z-\xi|$ ? as the LHS bracket is z

Comment: $z$ is a parameter in the integral, so the result of the integration depends on $z$, and is the logarithmic potential of $\mu$ evaluated at $z$.